# force response.Redirect() to display error for broken URL while compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible for Visual studio compiler to display error if the URL is not available when response.Redirect() is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since complete set of available Url is not known till run time and completely dynamic it is not possible to predict at compile/edit time.